# how to add distinct mulitple tables in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, express

```
import LetterTable from './LetterTable'

export default function Proposal1_letter(props) {

  const [table,settable] = useState([])
  const [tables,settables] = useState([])
  const [showtable,setshowtable] = useState(false)
  console.log("primary table",table)
  console.log("this is multiple tables",tables)

  const submittable = () => {
    settables([...tables,table])
    settable([])
  }
  return (
    <>


<button onClick={() => {setshowtable(true)}}>Add Tables</button>
{/* <div className='container-admin'> */}
      <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Proposal Letter</h2>
        <br></br>
        <div className="Letter" >
          <textarea type="text" cols={100} rows={8} style={{textAlign:'justify'}}
           className="form-control" name='letter' value={props.info.letter} onChange={props.change}  id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Your Letter Here" />
        </div>
      </form>
    {/* </div> */}
    <br>
    </br>
    <br/>
    <div>
    {tables.map((childtable) => {
      <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope='col'>SLNo.</th>
          <th scope="col">Activity</th>
          <th scope="col">Timeline</th>
          <th scope="col">Professional Fee</th>
          <th scope="col">Reimbursement</th>
          <th scope="col">Government Fees</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {childtable ? childtable.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td scope="row">{index + 1}</td>
          <td>{item.activity}</td>
          <td>{item.timeline}</td>
          <td>{item.prof_fee}</td>
          <td>{item.reimbursment_fee}</td>
          <td>{item.gov_fee}</td>
        </tr>
      )):null}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    })}
      


    </div>

    {showtable ? <LetterTable table = {table} settables= {settables} tables = {tables} settable = {settable} setshowtable = {setshowtable} submittable = {submittable}/> : null}



      
    </>
  )
}
```

```
export default function LetterTable(props) {
    
    const [content,setconent] = useState({activity:"",timeline:"",prof_fee:"",reimbursment_fee: "",gov_fee : ""})
    const [sample,setsample] = useState()

    const addRow = () => {
      console.log("i have been called")
      console.log(props.table)
        props.settable([...props.table,content]);
        setconent({
          activity: '',
          timeline: '',
          prof_fee: '',
          reimbursment_fee: '',
          gov_fee: ''
        });
      };

    const handle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // props.settable([...props.table,content])
        if (content.activity !== '' || content.timeline !== '' || content.prof_fee !== '' || content.reimbursment_fee !== '' || content.gov_fee  !== '') { // Check if any content is present
            addRow();
            console.log("yes it is ")
            }
        console.log("tables",props.tables)
        console.log("table",props.table)
        console.log(content)
        
        props.settables([...props.tables,props.table]);
        // props.settables([...props.tables,props.table])
        // props.submittable()
        
        // props.settables([...props.tables, props.table]) // 
        
        // setconent({activity:"",timeline:"",prof_fee:"",reimbursment_fee: "",gov_fee : ""})
        props.settable([])
        props.setshowtable(false)
    }

    const onchange = (e) => {
        setconent({...content,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }

    

  return (
    <div>
      <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Activity</th>
      <th scope="col">Timeline</th>
      <th scope="col">Professional Fee</th>
      <th scope="col">Reimbursement</th>
      <th scope="col">Government Fees</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {}
    <tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="activity"  value = {content.activity} onChange = {onchange} placeholder="Enter activity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="timeline" value = {content.timeline}onChange = {onchange} placeholder="Enter timeline" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prof_fee" value = {content.prof_fee}  onChange = {onchange} placeholder="Enter professional fee" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="reimbursment_fee" value = {content.reimbursment_fee} onChange = {onchange}placeholder="Enter reimbursement" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="gov_fee" value = {content.gov_fee} onChange = {onchange} placeholder="Enter government fees" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <button onClick={addRow}>Add Row</button>
  <br/>
  <button onClick={handle}> Submit Table </button>
</table>


    </div>
  )
}
```

I am populating the table with data and then transferring the data to a larger collection called 'tables.' This process functions as intended when I click the 'Add Row' button. However, when I directly attempt to submit the existing content from the table to 'tables' by clicking the 'Submit Table' button, even without using the 'Add Row' button, the 'tables' collection remains empty. I am unsure why this behavior is occurring.